# How to read "mean_file_proto" into OpenCV Mat in order to subtract image from mean to use in Caffe Model?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.2.

I downloaded a Caffe model containing a mean file `mean.binaryproto`. I want to subtract from my input image the mean.
How to read `mean_file_proto` into OpenCV Mat in order to subtract image from mean to use in Caffe Model?

**Edit**:

Can I use just OpenCV to do it without using Caffe? I am using OpenCV 3.2 in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 64bit. I get an image from the webcam and I want to subtract the mean then, using `OpenCV::dnn`, get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean file is planar, probably either 1 or 3 channels.  The scale is [0, 255].

```
caffe::BlobProto mean_proto;
caffe::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile( filename, &mean_proto ); // check return code
caffe::Blob< float > mean_blob;
mean_blob.FromProto( mean_proto );
float *data = mean_blob.mutable_cpu_data();
```

You can now create a `cv::Mat` of type `CV_32FC1`, for each channel.

```
cv::Mat channel( mean_blob.height(), mean_blob.width(), CV_32FC1, data );
data += mean_blob.height() * mean_blob.width();
```

Finally, populate a vector with these channels, and use `cv::merge()` to combine them into a single `cv::Mat` that you can subtract from another `cv::Mat` containing your input image.  If your image is already normalized [0, 1), you'll also need to rescale the mean.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use just OpenCV to do it without using Caffe? I am using OpenCV 3.2 in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 64bit. I get image from webcam and I want to subtract the mean then by using OpenCV::dnn get the result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, `ReadProtoFromBinaryFile()` is basically a wrapper around Google's Protobuf library.  See https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/util/io.cpp .  I have no direct experience with this library, but it appears to involve a parser generator that's fed a description of the data format.  If you don't want to link with Caffe, then it seems you'll have to run protobuf's protoc tool on https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto , in order to generate some of the functions used in `caffe::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile()`. See https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/22

Comment: @video-analysis-deep-learning You could also take advantage of Caffe's Python language bindings, and use it write a conversion tool to extract mean images from these files.